# Append dynamic divs to left side

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

i am adding divs dynamically at the bottom of screen. My problem is i want to add a div to left side of 1st div as used in facebook chatting.
I have created a jsfiddle example for more clarification
http://jsfiddle.net/Jsu4t/

```
<div id="ctrId1" class="draggable chatRoom " rel="0" style="float: right; bottom: 0; position:fixed; right: 0px; z-index: 1000; padding: 5px; background-color:whitesmoke;">
    <div class="header" style="background-color:#006dcc">
        <div  style="float:right;">
            <img id="imgDelete" class="imgClose" data-control="ctrId1"  style="cursor:pointer;" src="Images/x_icon_hover.png"/></div>
        <span class="selText" rel="0">rashmi</span></div>
    <div id="divMessage" class="messageArea"></div>
    <div class="buttonBar"  style="padding-top:10px;bottom:0px,position:absolute;"><input id="txtPrivateMessage" class="msgText" type="text"   />
        <input id="btnSendMessage" class="submitButton button" type="button" value="Send"   /></div></div>
```

In my code i am appending all the dynamic divs to a parent div, but still same issue.

Comment: You mentioned a problem, but didn't ask a question...?

Comment: yes, my problem is my question :)

Answer (score 0):

you can append multiple DIVs to first DIV, there are two way to keep all div in a single line starting from left.

You can use `"display:inline"` Or you can use `"float:left"` in DIV style.

Comment: i have tried both, but not working. I have updated my jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Jsu4t/2/

Answer (score 0):

This one works as expected I hope

jsfiddle.net/U2QDD/

Comment: yes its working fine with 2 divs. But in my case i am adding multiple divs dynamically.

Comment: I'm not sure, that we can solve this problem using CSS only, so this is my quick solution with jQuery jsfiddle.net/fVbdm/